# ScaleGestureDetector on Android fires onScaleEnd when pointers get too close

Tags: android, gesture

I'm using (API 25) ScaleGestureDetector, and it seems to run the `onScaleEnd()` method of its listeners simply when the pointers get too close.

(I've checked the two pointers still remain two pointers by using pointer overlay, so it's not a display/input issue.)

Since I would like the gesture to be continuous even if the changes are minimal, is there a way to bypass or at least lower this limit?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. When my fingers get about two centimeters apart, the onScale events stop and onScaleEnd is called. But the MotionEvent doesn't cancel until I lift my fingers, as expected. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @arlomedia Hi, I ended up writing my own detector from "scratch" - as in, I used a similar feature from an opensource project I found online, but I no longer have access to the relevant source code :(

Comment: Google says this is "working as intended": https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37131665

Comment: The gap is huge!!!! Cant believe this large gap would cancel pinch zoom. damn google

Comment: In iOS users can pinch in to zoom out until two fingers touch each other. In Android, you can zoom out only until two fingers are 2cm apart. It is ridiculous and also ridiculous in that "working as intended" thread.